# How to deal with dispatch write failed error of Apache IoTDB Version 0.14?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask that Apache IoTDB Version 0.14.0 preview 3 occasionally reported the "dispatch write failed" error. The code of the error are 506 and 338. Has anyone encountered this problem and what is the reason for this? I worried that this error may affect the data writing progress of IoTDB, will the data writing be interrupted or will the data be lost due to this error?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you tried to create time series concurrently in Apache IoTDB Version 0.14.0, only one will be successfully created, and other concurrently created threads will fail to be created.
In IoTDB Version 1.0, this log should have been changed to warning level, not error level. You can try to update to this version and try again.